# Merge multiple jupyter notebooks into single python program

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have multiple notebooks. I want to merge them into a single python program. can you suggest me the best way.

Sample scenario:

```
notebook1 ( has 2 dataframes):        
x , y

Notebook2 ( has 2 dataframes basically susbsets of notebook1 data frames):
 x1 = x['xxx'] >0
 y1= y['xxx'] >0

Notebook3 (has 3 dataframes):
 z,z1,z2

Notebook4: (uses all the dataframes from previous notebooks and performs operations).

output=x*z*z1*y1
```

What is the best method of creating say  "exec.py" that basically uses all the notebooks and gives the final output?
    Shall I covert each note book to a python program or  shall I convert each notebook to a function?

Please provide your insights. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this... but this sounds like a really icky way to build a process.  Why not write another `exec.py`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this straightforward and elegant [script](https://gist.github.com/fperez/e2bbc0a208e82e450f69) written by [Fernando Pérez](https://github.com/fperez). The script merges many Jupyter Notebooks into a single one.

I've tried and it works for me. I hope it helps you.